# How does call by reference in Python work?

Tags: python-3.x

Please explain when calling function first time the code follows call by reference. But when calling function second time it does not follow the same.

```
##functions 
num = [0,1,2,3,4]

def first(num1):
    num1.append([5, 6]);
    print(num1)

def second(num1):
    num1 = num1 + [7, 8];
    print(num1)

print(num)
first(num)
print(num)
second(num)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `first` the argument is passed by reference and modified inside the function using that reference.

In `second` the name `num1` is used but also assigned a new value.  The `num1` is bound to a new value and this does not change the original passed in.

Answer (score 0):

In first method you are appending a list to num1 that basically points to num at that point, So basically it refers to the same location while in second method you are adding a list to num1 which create a new location.
You can understand better by using the function id() which basically gives a unique integer value for every object.

```
##functions 
num = [0,1,2,3,4]

def first(num1):
    print(id(num1)) # obj reference
    num1.append([5, 6]);
    print(id(num1))
    print(num1)

def second(num1):
    print(id(num1))
    num1 = num1 + [7, 8];
    print(id(num1))
    print(num1)

print(num)
first(num)
print(num)
second(num)
print(num)
```

If you run the above code, you will find that the object reference is same in first method before and after operation, while in second method it is different.

OUTPUT:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
140360682379784
140360682379784
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
140360682379784 
140360672905160
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
```

And also this article would help you understand better about the concept of call by value and call by reference in python.
[Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

You can try the code here: [Code](https://repl.it/NncX/1)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I don't have min. reputation to comment link directly. That's why I have to put it in answer. Anyways,Thanks for your advice. I am also new to stack overflow. So, it would take sometime to do best practices.

Comment: If you don't have the reputation needed to make a comment then you *should not make a comment*, you should not make a comment using the *Post Your Answer* feature.